# Sending websocket message from elsewhere in an Express.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, express, websocket

I'm using [this ws library](https://github.com/websockets/ws) and have been able to correctly set up a websocket server and connection from a client.

I have all the logic inside of a class, and it looks like this (I've removed all business logic and other clutter that isn't really necessary, also please note that I'm using TypeScript):

```
import * as url from 'url';
import * as WebSocket from 'ws';

class Websocket {
    protected sitesObj: {};
    protected webSocketServer: any;

    public initConnections(server: any): void {
        this.webSocketServer = new WebSocket.Server({
            server,
            verifyClient: this.verifyClient.bind(this)
        });

        this.webSocketServer.on('connection', (webSocket: any, request: any): any => {
            // logic here to set up users and sites

            webSocket.send(`connected: ${userId} on site(s) ${siteId}`);
            webSocket.on('message', (message: any): any => {
                console.log('message from the client: ', message);
            });

            webSocket.on('close', (eventCode: any): any => {
                if (eventCode === 1006) {
                    console.log('Websocket disconnected abnormally');
                }
                if (eventCode === 1000) {
                    console.log('Websocket successfully closed normally');
                    // logic to remove user
                    webSocket.send(`deleted: ${userId} on site(s) ${siteId}`);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    public broadcast(data: any): any {
        this.webSocketServer.forEach((client: any): any => {
            client.send('test');
        });
    }

    private verifyClient(info: any, cb: any): any {
        // verification logic here
    }

}

const ws: Websocket = new Websocket();
export { ws };
```

There is an index file in this Express project (which is the entry point for the project) in which everything is essentially set up, including importing this `ws` class above. Once imported, this snippet runs: `ws.initConnections(this.instance);` where `this.instance` is the Express server. Clients can now attempt to connect to the websocket server and start sending and receiving messages.

My problem is, I cannot get the `broadcast` method to work in my app. I import this `ws` class into another part of my project, in which I want to trigger a broadcast. For example, in this other file I have:

```
import { ws } from '../../modules/websocket';
ws.broadcast('test');
```

However, this does not work. When the `broadcast` method is invoked, `webSocketServer` is undefined, and I'm not sure how I can target my stored websocket connections and send them messages through this method.

Here is the class in which the `initConnections` method is called, as request by @jfriend00 in the comments:

```
/**
 * @file Singleton server implementation.
 */

import * as express from 'express';
import * as http from 'http';

import { app } from './app';

import { ws } from '../modules/Websocket';

// Constants
const PORT: number = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10);
const HOST: string = process.env.HOST;

/**
 * Http Server Implementation
 *
 * @export
 * @class Server
 */
export class Server {
    /* Local instances for access */
    public app: express.Application;
    public instance: http.Server;

    /**
     * Creates an instance of Server
     *
     * @memberof Server
     */
    constructor() {
        this.instance = http.createServer(app);
        this.app = app;
    }

    /**
     * Starts the http server
     *
     * @memberof Server
     */
    public start(port: number = null): void {
        const PORT_NUMBER: number = port || PORT;
        if (this.instance.address()) {
            logger.warn({
                action: 'ServiceStart',
                message: 'Server already started.', port: this.instance.address().port
            });
            return;
        }
        this.instance.listen(PORT_NUMBER, HOST);
        this.instance.on('listening', this.onListening);
        this.instance.on('error', this.onError);
        ws.initConnections(this.instance);
    }

    /**
     * Returns URL of the app service
     *
     * @memberof Server
     */
    public getAppServiceUrl(): string {
        /* TODO: get the proper protocol (will eventually be https) */
        /* tslint:disable-next-line */
        return `http://${HOST}:${PORT}`;
    }

    // ... plus a few other methods here

}

/**
 * @export
 * Singleton instance of http server
 */
const server: Server = new Server();
export { server };
```

Comment: How and where is the method `initConnections()` called since that's where `this.webSocketServer` is assigned.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's called from within another class that is imported into the main index entry point. This custom class (named `Server` sets up an http server, passing in an express app, and does things like starts the express server and has listeners for if the server is stopped, etc.)

Comment: I'm asking you to show us the code where you call `initConnections()` because that appears to be the method that isn't working properly.

Comment: Geez.  Please don't ever make two symbols that are so close to one another like `Websocket` and `WebSocket`.  That's a nightmare for others to read, understand and not get confused.  Had me confused for awhile.  Ruins the readability of the code.  The module should probably be something like `webSocketLib` or just `ws`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've added the code where the method is called. In the index file, we require it and then start our server: `const { server } = require('./server');
    server.start();`

Comment: Kind of a weird design where you go to all the trouble to define classes for your webSocket and Server instances, but then you hardwire them together as singletons.  Your server class really should instantiate a new WebSocket server object rather than import one that is already made.  Then, it would be a lot more reusable.  If I were troubleshooting this, I'd set a  breakpoint on the `initConnections()` method and see what `this` is pointing to and watch it do its initialization and then set a breakpoint on the `broadcast` method and see what `this` is pointing to.

Comment: You don't show where you're attempting to call the `broadcast()` method from so that's another point of examination to see if it really has the right object at that point.